# how to sync time to android

Tags: java, android, url, synchronization

i have a url given to me to used for syncing the server time to my application, 
Question is how to do that? anyone can explain to me what to do here thank i really appreciate it.

here's the URL = http://server10.instaforex.com:2012/TimeService/TimeService.svc/CurrentTime

here is my mainactivity code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Timer timeoutTimer;
    final Random myRandom = new Random();
    GenerateTask genTask = new GenerateTask();
    static String RAN_TEXT = "text";

    class GenerateTask extends TimerTask {
        boolean started = false;
        public void run() {
            if (started) {
                System.out.println("generating");
                final TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.generatenumber);
                RAN_TEXT = "";

                for(int k=0;k<7;k++){
                    RAN_TEXT += myRandom.nextInt(10) + " ";
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textGenerateNumber.setText(RAN_TEXT);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonGenerate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.generateme);

        buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("click");
                if (!genTask.started) {
                    genTask.started=true;
                    timeoutTimer = new Timer();
                    timeoutTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(genTask, 0, 30000);
                } else {
                    genTask.started=false;
                    timeoutTimer.cancel();
                }
            }
       });  
    }
}
```

Comment: what is question here ?

Comment: question is how to sync the time from the given link to my application?

Comment: I think you need to parse the result of that link using parsers like
Jericho try this link.. http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html

Comment: Do you specifically need to sync with the server time or will NTP UTC time do ? I'd expect a server to be synced with NTP anyway.

Comment: can you guys please show me how to do that base on my code above? for future reference also. TIA

Comment: Your link is very useful, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

**First** try to get the source of that html link using either one of solutions from the links of SO
[solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview?answertab=votes#tab-top) or [solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966760/how-i-get-page-source-from-webview)

**Second** you can parse its content using [parsers](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html).

**Third** Display the parsed content as required time format.

Let me know if you face any difficulty..

Comment: The link returns a XML. Why would you load it into a webview and then extract it when you can parse the contents directly ? The answer you linked to does that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview?answertab=votes#

Comment: @deepak and Adarsh can you please show me how to do this base on my code above??

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what your main activity is up to from the code you posted. It just concatenates some random numbers and sets them in a text area.

If you're looking to parse XML output returned by a HTTP client, there are many examples out there that show you how to do this. Take a look at this question - [Android: parse XML from string problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752268/android-parse-xml-from-string-problems)

If NTP time is what you are really interested in, there are [NTP clients for android that can help you sycn time correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677674/use-of-ntp-service).

Use one of those solutions and you're good to go.

Comment: my bad i didnt explain my code, so here i'll explain, and you are correct actually it's a password generator code once button is click it will generate random 7 digits for every 30 secs. I want to sync the time of my application to the URL they gave me, as you can see the application has its own time so i want it to sync to their server. can you please give me and example base on my code above?? for future reference also